# Reading file with different start and end delimiters in java

Tags: java, io

I am trying to implement meeting scheduling algorithm. I want to randomly generate meetings and store it in a file. Then read this file in another code, create different agents who will try to schedule these meetings.

My input meeting file is as follows:

```
1  20  25  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [4, 5]

2  21  29  [1, 6, 7, 5, 33]  [1, 5, 33]
```

from left to right, these values indicate meeting id, start time, hard deadline, attendees ID list, Essential attendees ID list.

Basically it is combination of integers and integer arraylist(dynamic,size not fixed).
To store this, I have used this code

```
File fleExample = new File("Meeting.txt")
PrintWriter M1 = new PrintWriter(fleExample);
M1.print(m.getMeetingID()+" "+m.getStartTime()+" "+m.getHardDeadLine()+" "+m.getAttendees()+" "+m,getEssentialAttendees());
M1.println();
```

I want to read these values and set it to integer variables and integer arraylist.

```
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Meeting.txt");
  DataInputStream inp = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inp));
  String strLine;
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        String[] tokens = strLine.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < MeetingCount; i++) {
               Meeting meet = new Meeting();
               meet.setMeetingID(Integer.valueOf(tokens[0]));
               meet.setStartTime(Integer.valueOf(tokens[1]));
               meet.setHardDeadLine(Integer.valueOf(tokens[2]));
        }
   }
```

**I am able to set the values to integers but could not find a way to do the same for arraylist.I want to do store the string to arraylist.** Any help in this direction will be great.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried for getting the list?

Comment: I would split this into two problems, extracting pieces like [71 45 33] from the input, and building an ArrayList from it. Which part is difficult?

Comment: Hi, I have added more details about writing this in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your implementation is for (and what the `Meeting` object is about), but if you just want to assign them to either int or list variable, try using a scanner and reading them one by one:

```
String str = "1 20 25 [1 2 3] [4 5]";

Scanner scan = new Scanner(str);
int intVariable = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> listVariable = null; //null marks no active list

while (scan.hasNext()) { //try/catch here is highly recommeneded!

    //read next input (separated by whitespace)
    String next = scan.next();

    if (next.startsWith("[")) {
        //init new list and store first value into it
        listVariable = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        listVariable.add(Integer.parseInt(next.substring(1)));
    } else if (next.endsWith("]")) {
        //add the last item to the list
        listVariable.add(Integer.parseInt(next.substring(0, next.length()-1)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listVariable.toArray()));
        //reset the list to null
        listVariable = null;
    } else {
        //if inside a list, add it to list, otherwise it is simply an integer
        if (listVariable != null) {
            listVariable.add(Integer.parseInt(next));
        } else {
            intVariable = Integer.parseInt(next);
            System.out.println(intVariable);
        }
    }
}
```

Here i simply printed the output, but you can of course project this to whatever need you have, or have a list of integer values and a list of integer list values.

Also note, in this example I just took one line of the file, but you can provide scanner with your file directly (no need to read it yourself line by line).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
String fileinput="2 21 29 [6 7] [71 45 33]";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");    
Matcher m=p.matcher(fileinput);
while (m.find()) {
    int i=Integer.parseInt(fileinput.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Above problem is solved by using regex where it searches for one or more integers continuously and break when they could not find no more integers.
This process will repeat till the end of the string. m.find will returns the start and end location of the identified pattern. Using start and end values we extracts the substring from the main string and then parsing as Integer.

Comment: I assume the question is to convert [1 2 3] String to arraylist of type integer in a preciese way, if I am not wrong

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mohan Raj. It added to my knowledge, but found a different way by splitting  integers and arraylist in two files.